# How to sample points on a triangle surface in 3D?

Tags: geometry, triangles, 3d, random, solid-geometry

To take random uniform points inside a triangle [Triangle Point Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrianglePointPicking.html) method is used. But this is for 2D points, how can I take random points from a triangle that is defined by 3 arbitrary 3D points?

In other words, let's say I have 3 points in 3D space, and these points define a plane, how can I take random points on the plane such that my points are uniformly sampled inside the triangle that is defined by these 3 points?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can probably project onto the xy, xz, or yz planes, pick a point, and then project back up. The jacobian of these maps will be constant, so my guess is that uniformly of choice is not destroyed.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of this also, but I was avoiding extra calculation. I mean, let's say that I project onto xy plane and pick points, when back projecting I need to calculate z value of all points using the first 3 points z value. And beside that I'm not sure if it is still be uniform, can you explain it little bit more detailed? What do you mean by jacobian will be constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same exact algorithm should work in $3D$ too:
$$\vec{x} = \vec{v_1} + a (\vec{v_2} -\vec{v_1}) + b (\vec{v_3} -\vec{v_1})$$
Where $a,b$ are uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ and the $\vec{v}$'s are the triangle vertices in $3D$.

Comment: I'll be back, after I try this :)

Comment: This will not work in some cases, such as when $a$ and $b$ are both $1$. In that case, $x$ will be $v_2 + v_3 - v_1$, which is probably not inside the triangle.

Comment: Important note: if $a + b >= 1$ then it will extend past the triangle. In such a case, set $a = 1 - a$ and $b = 1 - b$.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, this formulation is not guaranteed to give you points on the triangle. The correct formulation is as follow:

$P = (1 - \sqrt{a})v1 + (\sqrt{a} (1 - b))v2 + (b \sqrt{a})v3$

where $a, b \sim U[0, 1]$.