# Formula name to scatter 3D points in a triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, 3d, random, solid-geometry

I was looking for how to scatter a 3D point into a triangle surface and I found the answer in this post here:
[How to sample points on a triangle surface in 3D?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/538458/1119487)

Basically, the formula that I was looking for was this one:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4023675/1119487

Does anyone know what the name of this formula is, please? I want to research more about it but I don't know where I can start.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you expect that this *should* have a name?  Generally speaking, things are only named if they appear often enough that it is worth increasing the cognitive burden on the reader to make them learn a new term.  I cannot imagine that the problem of uniformly choosing a point from a triangle or tetrahedron occurs frequently enough to merit a special name, let alone a particular algorithm for doing so.

Comment: Hm make sense. Do you know where did he presume this algorithm?

Comment: Are you asking for a source for the algorithm?  I have no idea.  Perhaps you could ask the original answerer (you will need to earn a little bit of reputation on the site before you can post a comment, but the bar is pretty low; post one well-received question or answer; or edit 8 posts).